# Is FORMATMESSAGE returns several string for one parameter value?

Tags: sql-server

FORMATMESSAGE function returns NULL when one parameter value using for several 
msg string.

```
DECLARE @myvar VARCHAR(10) = 100

SELECT FORMATMESSAGE ('First value %s, Second value %s' , @myvar) AS String
```

Expected result: First value 100, Second value 100

Actual   result: First value 100, Second value null

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify each parameter:

```
DECLARE @myvar VARCHAR(10) = 100
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE ('First value %s, Second value %s' , @myvar, @myvar) AS String
```

Comment: Hi, Kristofer
Thank you! But what to do if I will have variable amount of "%s", for example, 70? It is improperly to repeat @myvar 70 times.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot do that with `FORMATMESSAGE` without adding your variable 70 times. If you want to repeat the same value many times you can use `REPLICATE`: `SELECT REPLICATE('repeat this', 20)`.

Comment: I used `REPLACE ` function -   `SELECT REPLACE ('First value %s, Second value %s' , '%s', @myvar) AS String`